# Android ListView don't smooth scroll using ViewHolder

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Hello and sorry for another list view scroll issue, I'm implementing a list view on Android but it doesn't scrolls smoothly. I have Added a ViewHolder pattern and I have tried to set only a textview for row but still doesn't work. And I don't think that I'm doing to much work on UI threat cause the container activity only have 3 static buttons.

Here is my Adapter getView function:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // get layout reference
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_search, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        // Get the reference to layout
        holder.ivColorSearch = convertView.findViewById(R.id.vi_color_search);
        holder.tvColorDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_color_desc);
        holder.position = position;

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Set colo+r description
    holder.tvColorDesc.setText(dataSet.get(position).name + "\n" + fandeckNames.get(dataSet.get(position).fandeck));

    // Set image color
    GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) holder.ivColorSearch.getBackground();
    int color = Color.parseColor(dataSet.get(position).colorCode);
    drawable.setColor(color);

    // Set the listener
    holder.ivColorSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.tvColorDesc.setOnClickListener(this);

    holder.ivColorSearch.setTag(position);
    holder.tvColorDesc.setTag(position);

    return convertView;
}
```

As you can see every row only have a View(it was a Image view but I'm trying to improve it) to set it's background color and a TextView.
If I remove the set image and set text code blocks it directly doesn't scroll, I can't understand why.

Here is my list view xml declaration (it is in a custom view):

```
    <RelativeLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:background="@android:color/black"
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">


<!-- Search field -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_search"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:inputType="textFilter"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_edittext"/>

<!-- Colors list -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_search_colors"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:divider="@null">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here my row code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_language_item"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="50dp">

<View
    android:id="@+id/vi_color_search"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_image"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_color_desc"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:lines="2"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance, if you need more info, please ask, I've been with this issue since Saturday, I have tested lots of different solutions but I think that this is the better way to implement a list view.

Comment: I suggest you use a RecyclerView instead of a ListView with ViewHolder. Give it a try.

Comment: What is the real size of your `rounded_corners_image` drawable?
As you're applying some transformations on it, it could be that

Comment: Does `dataset` happen to be a `LinkedList`?

Comment: - Eselfar: I have tried removing completly the images and nothing happen. 
- Ben P: daset is an arraylist of a custom class 
- jerubio: I will try it
Thanks to all answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED, I'm really sorry, it was my fault. I was overriding the on touch listener of list view in the container activity.

An advice: don't copy paste jeje